# bazel can not build the project external dependency

Tags: c++, c++11, build, bazel, bazel-rules

We have a RPC project. it use bazel build.
In this worksapce, it have dome other projects.
like

```
http_archive(
    name = "com_github_google_crc32c",  # 2021-10-05T19:47:30Z
    build_file = "//bazel:third_party/crc32c/BUILD.bazel",
    sha256 = "ac07840513072b7fcebda6e821068aa04889018f24e10e46181068fb214d7e56",
    strip_prefix = "crc32c-1.1.2",
    urls = ["https://github.com/google/crc32c/archive/1.1.2.tar.gz"],
)
```

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library", "cc_test")

genrule(
    name = "crc32c_config_h",
    srcs = ["src/crc32c_config.h.in"],
    outs = ["crc32c/crc32c_config.h"],
    cmd = """
sed -e 's/#cmakedefine01/#define/' \
""" + select({
        "@//bazel/config:brpc_with_sse42": """-e 's/ HAVE_SSE42/ HAVE_SSE42 1/' \
""",
        "//conditions:default": """-e 's/ HAVE_SSE42/ HAVE_SSE42 0/' \
""",
    }) + select({
        "@//bazel/config:brpc_with_glog": """-e 's/ CRC32C_TESTS_BUILT_WITH_GLOG/ CRC32C_TESTS_BUILT_WITH_GLOG 1/' \
""",
        "//conditions:default": """-e 's/ CRC32C_TESTS_BUILT_WITH_GLOG/ CRC32C_TESTS_BUILT_WITH_GLOG 0/' \
""",
    }) + """-e 's/ BYTE_ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN/ BYTE_ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN 0/' \
    -e 's/ HAVE_BUILTIN_PREFETCH/ HAVE_BUILTIN_PREFETCH 0/' \
    -e 's/ HAVE_MM_PREFETCH/ HAVE_MM_PREFETCH 0/' \
    -e 's/ HAVE_ARM64_CRC32C/ HAVE_ARM64_CRC32C 0/' \
    -e 's/ HAVE_STRONG_GETAUXVAL/ HAVE_STRONG_GETAUXVAL 0/' \
    -e 's/ HAVE_WEAK_GETAUXVAL/ HAVE_WEAK_GETAUXVAL 0/' \
    < $< > $@
""",
)

cc_library(
    name = "crc32c",
    srcs = [
        "src/crc32c.cc",
        "src/crc32c_arm64.cc",
        "src/crc32c_arm64.h",
        "src/crc32c_arm64_check.h",
        "src/crc32c_internal.h",
        "src/crc32c_portable.cc",
        "src/crc32c_prefetch.h",
        "src/crc32c_read_le.h",
        "src/crc32c_round_up.h",
        "src/crc32c_sse42.cc",
        "src/crc32c_sse42.h",
        "src/crc32c_sse42_check.h",
        ":crc32c_config_h",
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "include/crc32c/crc32c.h",
    ],
    copts = select({
        "@//bazel/config:brpc_with_sse42": ["-msse4.2"],
        "//conditions:default": [],
    }),
    strip_include_prefix = "include",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_test(
    name = "crc32c_test",
    srcs = [
        "src/crc32c_arm64_unittest.cc",
        "src/crc32c_extend_unittests.h",
        "src/crc32c_portable_unittest.cc",
        "src/crc32c_prefetch_unittest.cc",
        "src/crc32c_read_le_unittest.cc",
        "src/crc32c_round_up_unittest.cc",
        "src/crc32c_sse42_unittest.cc",
        "src/crc32c_test_main.cc",
        "src/crc32c_unittest.cc",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":crc32c",
        "@com_google_googletest//:gtest",
        "@com_google_googletest//:gtest_main",
    ] + select({
        "@//bazel/config:brpc_with_glog": ["@com_github_google_glog//:glog"],
        "//conditions:default": [],
    }),
)
```

and we must write the BUILD file for it.
But when we want to make it becomes externally dependent, bazel can not build it.

[image]

any guys know how to solve it?
yep, i think maybe add some scrpt is a good idea?
maybe i think some scrpt can slove it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that `@com_github_madler_zlib` is missing. You need this external dependency e.g. add to your `WORKSPACE` file:

```
http_archive(
    name = "com_github_madler_zlib",
    build_file = "//zlib.BUILD",
    sha256 = "629380c90a77b964d896ed37163f5c3a34f6e6d897311f1df2a7016355c45eff",
    strip_prefix = "zlib-1.2.11",
    urls = ["https://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz"],
)
```

and *zlib.BUILD*:

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")

licenses(["notice"])  # BSD/MIT-like license (for zlib)

_ZLIB_HEADERS = [
    "crc32.h",
    "deflate.h",
    "gzguts.h",
    "inffast.h",
    "inffixed.h",
    "inflate.h",
    "inftrees.h",
    "trees.h",
    "zconf.h",
    "zlib.h",
    "zutil.h",
]

_ZLIB_PREFIXED_HEADERS = ["zlib/include/" + hdr for hdr in _ZLIB_HEADERS]

# In order to limit the damage from the `includes` propagation
# via `:zlib`, copy the public headers to a subdirectory and
# expose those.
genrule(
    name = "copy_public_headers",
    srcs = _ZLIB_HEADERS,
    outs = _ZLIB_PREFIXED_HEADERS,
    cmd = "cp $(SRCS) $(@D)/zlib/include/",
)

cc_library(
    name = "zlib",
    srcs = [
        "adler32.c",
        "compress.c",
        "crc32.c",
        "deflate.c",
        "gzclose.c",
        "gzlib.c",
        "gzread.c",
        "gzwrite.c",
        "infback.c",
        "inffast.c",
        "inflate.c",
        "inftrees.c",
        "trees.c",
        "uncompr.c",
        "zutil.c",
        # Include the un-prefixed headers in srcs to work
        # around the fact that zlib isn't consistent in its
        # choice of <> or "" delimiter when including itself.
    ] + _ZLIB_HEADERS,
    hdrs = _ZLIB_PREFIXED_HEADERS,
    copts = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:windows": [],
        "//conditions:default": [
            "-Wno-unused-variable",
            "-Wno-implicit-function-declaration",
        ],
    }),
    includes = ["zlib/include/"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Comment: yep, i know this is less zlib_lib. but the problem is that we have add the BUILD file in the RPC project. It's not matter add the zlib BUILD file to the our project.

Comment: Call http_archive(name = "com_github_madler_zlib" before you call the other project